# Laravel Auth::attempt() on custom field names

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I have two password fields `password` and `master_password`. I can login the user with `password` field with `Auth()->guard('appusers')->attempt($data)` where **$data** is like following.

```
$data = [
    'username' => $username,
    'password'  => $password
];
```

But I cannot login the users by `master_password`. What should be my approach?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend would be to continue with the authentication that Laravel has by default. You need in your `LoginController` overwrite the `credentials` method from `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. For example:

```php
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $passwordOrMasterPassword = $request->has('master_password') ?
        $request->master_password :
        $request->password;

    return [
        'email'    => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $passwordOrMasterPassword,
    ];
}
```

You can play with the data in this method however you like.